# How to select from system hour and minutes from 10 to 70

Tags: sql-server

I came up with the following challenge:

I need to select somehow from the system values from 10 to 70 minute by minute, as the following example.

*Hour*

10:00

10:01

10:02

..

..

..

69:59

Is it possible?

Comment: This sounds like a homework question.  Have you made any effort to solve it yourself before you posted here?

Comment: Yes, i tried several times... And I'm doing this by myself, fortunately not a homework.

Comment: `Yes, i tried several times...` Please show what you've tried so far.

Comment: What do you mean "select from the system"?   Do you have a table?   What's in the table?

Comment: Last attemp i could get the top from row_number() with:

"SELECT TOP 61 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NAME) + 9 AS hora
FROM SYS.ALL_OBJECTS"


But it only gives an integer result from 10 to 70

Comment: This isn't the right venue for a "challenge". On Stack Overflow. We expect people to ask us about *practical* programming problems they're having issues with, preferably with the code they're trying to use, expected and actual results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach, using recursive CTEs to generate the sequences you need for the hours and minutes:

```
DECLARE @start_hour int = 10;
DECLARE @end_hour int = 69;
DECLARE @start_minute int = 0;
DECLARE @end_minute int = 59;

WITH hours AS (
    SELECT @start_hour hour
    UNION ALL
    SELECT hour + 1 FROM hours WHERE hour < @end_hour
),
minutes AS (
    SELECT @start_minute minute
    UNION ALL
    SELECT minute + 1 FROM minutes WHERE minute < @end_minute
)

SELECT
    CAST(hour AS VARCHAR(2)) + ':' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(minute AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)
FROM hours
CROSS JOIN minutes
ORDER BY
    hour,
    minute;
```

### Demo

The two sequences above represent the possible values for hours and minutes.  We use a cross join to generate all combinations.  Note that the minutes needs to be left padded with zero for the case where `minute` might take on a value between 0 and 9.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly how i should approach the situation, just couldn't figure out how!